# Как убрать точку в конце у числового значения

Tags: wordpress

Есть код ниже, через которое выводится числовые значения например 10.20.30, 111.222.333, эти значения выводятся нормально без точки на конце, а если значения числовые будут целыми, например 1,3,5,10,20,100, то в конце будет точка стоять. как можно избавиться от точки на конце в целых числах.

```
<?php $data = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'version', true) ;
         $result=explode('.' , $data);
         echo $result[0].'.'.$result[1];
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поменяйте последнюю строку на

```
echo $result[0];
if (count($result) > 1) {
    echo "." . $result[1];
}
```

Comment: спасибо лучший код из всех предложенных на разных форумах

Comment: Хорошо, я рад. Тогда, пожалуйста, пометьте ответ как принятый. Для этого нужно поставить под ответом галочку.